# How do you change the Emergency Alert tone on Android to a custom tone?

Tags: alerts

I am trying to build a **Custom ROM** for my phone, and I need a way to change the tone so that the default one doesn't get annoying.

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Please note that ROM development is off-topic since Android Enthusiasts focuses on end-users and power users (who are not necessarily developers) solving their issues. Thus, while this community might explain the technicality of Android OS to your queries, coding solutions are out of the scope of this community. For programming questions, you might want to try our sister site [so].